# Checkbox ischeck or uncheck android

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have a question regarding the ischecked or unchecked of the checkbox in my listview. I realize that the way that I implement my checkbox is different from others.

in mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.luenwong.checkboxtest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button bn;
ListView listView;
CheckBox chkAll;
String[] android_versions = { "ID:1", "ID:2", "ID:3", "ID:4", "ID:5", "ID:6", "ID:7", "ID:8", "ID:9" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    chkAll = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkAll);
    bn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStore);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, android_versions);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int itemCount = listView.getCount();
            for(int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
            {
                if(((CheckBox) view).isChecked()){
                    System.out.println("hey there");
            }
            }
        }
    });

    View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) view;
            int itemCount = listView.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
                System.out.println("correct: "+adapter.getItem(i));
                listView.setItemChecked(i, chk.isChecked());
            }
        }
    };

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkAll);
            int checkedItemCount = getCheckedItemCount();
            if (listView.getCount() == checkedItemCount)
                chk.setChecked(true);
            else
                chk.setChecked(false);
        }
    };

    chkAll.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

}
    private int getCheckedItemCount(){
        int cnt = 0;
        SparseBooleanArray positions = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        int itemCount = listView.getCount();

        for(int i=0;i<itemCount;i++){
            if(positions.get(i))
                cnt++;
        }

    return cnt;

    }
}
```

In XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="selectALL"
            />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkAll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="getGet"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


           android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonStore"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="ADD Checkbox"
            ></Button>

       </LinearLayout>
```

I really don't know how to check my checkbox with this method. As the checkbox is not created based on checkbox tag in XML.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use a OnClickListener with a checkbox, but rather a onCheckedChangeListener.

```
mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view ,boolean isChecked) {
        if(view.isChecked) {
            // Do something
        } else {
            // Do something else
        }


        }
    });
```

Comment: hi @Nick Asher. thank you for the response but the tutorial is having multiple checkbox in the XML and I dont have it in mine.